# cannot access memory at address 0X1 after setting up gdb and eclipse to debug shared library from Android Application

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I have two Android Projects: one is a library and the other a regular application using this library. My aim is to debug the shared library from the android application. I followed this guide:

http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/

And I commented out the the last line

```
##$GDBCLIENT -x `native_path $GDBSETUP`
```

But the following line

```
##cp -f $GDBSETUP_INIT $GDBSETUP
```

complains with the message:

`it cannot stat ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup`

so I commented it out since I think Eclipse will uploaded it for me. Besides that I made sure that:

- In both Android.mk I put LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Wall –g
- I am getting the .so in the libs library of the application
- I made debuggable true in the application
- The gdb2.setup path modified in order to refer both to the .so using solib-search-path ./libs/armeabi-v7a/ and the source is get referenced using directory

After stepping in the System.LoadLibrary instruction I executed the ndk-build-eclipse 
and no errors were produced and when I started debugging natively I got:

> Cannot access memory at address 0x1

and on Cygwin I got:

> Remote debugging from host 0.0.0.0

Here's the output of running the ndk-gdb-eclipse command:

```
$ ./ndk-gdb-eclipse --adb=/cygdrive/c/Utilities/adt-bundle-windows/adt-bundle-windows/sdk/platform-tools/adb --project=/cygdrive/c/Projects/IDSmart/IDSmartApp/IDSmart  --force --port=5039 --verbose
Android NDK installation path: /cygdrive/c/Utilities/android-ndk-r8c-windows/android-ndk-r8c/.
Using specific adb command: /cygdrive/c/Utilities/adt-bundle-windows/adt-bundle-windows/sdk/platform-tools/adb
ADB version found: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31
Using ADB flags:
Using specified project path: /cygdrive/c/Projects/IDSmart/IDSmartApp/IDSmart
Found package name: uk.co.idscan.idsmart
ABIs targetted by application: armeabi-v7a
Device API Level: 15
Device CPU ABIs: armeabi-v7a armeabi
Compatible device ABI: armeabi-v7a
Using gdb setup init: ./libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
Using toolchain prefix: /cygdrive/c/Utilities/android-ndk-r8c-windows/android-ndk-r8c/./toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
Using app out directory: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a
Found debuggable flag: true
Found device gdbserver: /data/data/uk.co.idscan.idsmart/lib/gdbserver
Found data directory: '/data/data/uk.co.idscan.idsmart'
Found running PID: 7922
7922
Killing existing debugging session
## COMMAND: adb_cmd shell kill -9 7864
/system/bin/sh: kill: 7864: Operation not permitted
Launched gdbserver succesfully.
Setup network redirection
## COMMAND: adb_cmd shell run-as uk.co.idscan.idsmart lib/gdbserver +debug-socket --attach 7922
## COMMAND: adb_cmd forward tcp:5039 localfilesystem:/data/data/uk.co.idscan.idsmart/debug-socket
Attached; pid = 7922
Listening on Unix socket debug-socket
## COMMAND: adb_cmd pull /system/bin/app_process obj/local/armeabi-v7a/app_process
1373 KB/s (9848 bytes in 0.007s)
Pulled app_process from device/emulator.
## COMMAND: adb_cmd pull /system/bin/linker obj/local/armeabi-v7a/linker
2147 KB/s (39592 bytes in 0.018s)
Pulled linker from device/emulator.
## COMMAND: adb_cmd pull /system/lib/libc.so obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libc.so
2576 KB/s (282316 bytes in 0.107s)
Pulled libc.so from device/emulator.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cannot access memory at address 0x1
```

Post your gdb2.setup file, the same one that you are using in eclipse.

Typically, these cannot access memory are due to solib-search-path being incorrect. Try entering absolute path to your project lib folder in your gdb2.setup file. For example, I have it set as:

```
set solib-search-path D:/android/android-ndk-r8d/samples/hello-jni/obj/local/armeabi
```

Let me know if it help.

Comment: Had the issue but found that the my gdb.setup has: set solib-search-path ./obj/local/arm64-v8a which contains the .so that I need the symbols from. Does it have to use abs path here?