# Debug Android Native located in dependent eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-ndk

(ADK 21, NDK r8d, Eclipse Juno)
[I've built several Android apps so decent experience using ADK/NDK etc]

Eclipse project setup:

```
- AppProject (android, java, no jni)
- LibProject (android, java, Yes jni)
```

Previously, all of it was in one project - builds fine, runs fine, and native debugging worked great.

Then I split off the "reusable" portion to make a library of common code to use with multiple "AppProject" application front ends. (Everything still builds, links, packs, and runs okay)

However, when I run "AppProject", I can no longer debug the native library.

What is the solution?

Possible option #1:

```
- Modify "LibProject" Android.mk to export a PreBuilt that is used by AppProject?
- (I would have all the debug symbols so I'm thinking that would work okay)
```

Would I need to cnature the AppProject as well? In other words, so it has an Android.mk to import the output .so from LibProject

Possible option #2

```
- http://stackoverflow.com/a/14344377/735533
- that workaround uses ndk-gdb
- I'm hoping for a solution where I can debug LibProject in Eclipse directly when running AppProject
```

Is there a better way to debug the native code located in the dependent project "LibProject" when running the main application "AppProject"?

Tia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those curious ...

- I tried prebuilts ...

  - And it definitely seems the be the way to go (test project setup worked)
  - But the structure of *my* codebase is a bit heavy on the native/non-native crosstalk and didn't want to take the time (yet) to do a proper reorganization at the moment.
  - However, restructuring as a prebuilt is on my "Important ToDo" list now

Anywhere, here is my solution.

On Linux (unix flavors) ... use links - the sources are linked into each AppProject from LibProject.

Basically the "LibProject" becomes a sort of "template" during development - it is not built or used as a library directly. Rather, each AppProject becomes self-sufficient, standalone, application with the contents of the library project embedded in its own code tree. Best part is native debugging works like a charm again.

Although it *sort of* defeats the point of making, there are benefits - one common codebase for the "library" portion ... which is really what I desire for the time being.

Also, conversion to use as a true Library dependency by the Application projects for, say, eventual release builds is an easy switch. Once debugged and ready, the Library can be built separately, packed normally with the application "front ends", and upgraded independently of the applications.